# Creating objects with associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I have Clients and Users. And Users can have many Clients.

The models are setup as so:

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :client_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :client_users
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :client_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :clients, through: :client_users
end

class ClientUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :client
end
```

So if I wanted to create a new client that had the first two users associated with it how would I do it?

e.g.

```
Client.create!(name: 'Client1', client_users: [User.first, User.second])
```

Trying that gives me the error:

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: ClientUser(#70142396623360) expected, got #<User id: 1,...
```

I also want to do this for an RSpec test. e.g.

```
user1 = create(:user)
user2 = create(:user)

client1 = create(:client, client_users: [user1, user2])
```

How do I create a client with associated users for in both the Rails console and in an RSpec test?

Comment: Try This
`User.create(name: 'oneuser')

User.create(name: 'twouser')

@client = Client.create(name: 'Client1')

@client.users << User.first

@client.users << User.second`

Comment: @VaibhavDhoke So the client has to exist first? I can't create and associate at the same time?

Comment: This is one way of doing it, maybe that also could be done, but I am not aware of it. still. Please refer this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) for more info.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to accept_nested_attributes for anything, as documented [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/create) you can also pass block to create.

```
Client.create!(name: 'Client1') do |client1| 
  client1.users << [User.find(1), User.find(2), User.find(3)]     
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It should work

> Client.create!(name: 'Client1').client_users.new([{user_id:
>   User.first},{user_id: User.second}])

Comment: @Cameron Try above solution

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the following code:

```
user1 = create(:user)
user2 = create(:user)

client1 = create(:client, users: [user1, user2])
```

See [ClassMethods/has_many](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) for the documentation

> collection=objects
>
> Replaces the collections content by deleting and adding objects as
>   appropriate. If the :through option is true callbacks in the join
>   models are triggered except destroy callbacks, since deletion is
>   direct.

If you are using [factory_girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) you can add `trait :with_users` like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :client do

    trait :with_two_users do
      after(:create) do |client|
        client.users = create_list :user, 2
      end
    end

  end
end
```

Now you can create a client with users in test like this:

```
client = create :client, :with_two_users
```

Answer (score 0):

> accepts_nested_attributes_for :users

and do as so:

> `Client.create!(name: 'Client1', users_attributes: { ........ })`

hope this would work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `after_create` callback

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :client_users, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: :client_users

  after_create :add_users

  private def add_users
    sef.users << [User.first, User.second]
  end
end
```

Alternatively, A simpler approach would be

```
Client.create!(name: 'Client1', user_ids: [User.first.id, User.second.id])
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're getting a mismatch is because you're specifying the `client_users` association that expects `ClientUser` instances, but you're passing in `User` instances:

```
# this won't work
Client.create!(client_users: [User.first, User.second])
```

Instead, since you already specified a `users` association, you can do this:

```
Client.create!(users: [User.first, User.second])
```

There's a simpler way to handle this, though: ditch the join model and use a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship. You still need a `clients_users` join table in the database, but you don't need a `ClientUser` model. Rails will handle this automatically under the covers.

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class User
  has_and_belongs_to_many :clients
end

# Any of these work:
client = Client.new(name: "Kung Fu")
user = client.users.new(name: "Panda")
client.users << User.new(name: "Nemo")
client.save # => this will create two users and a client, and add two records to the `clients_users` join table
```